# sendind emil in codeigniter to multiple emailids

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
function send_letter()
{
    echo $description =  $this->input->post('description',true);
    $this->load->model('newsletter_model');
    $this->data['mail_list'] = $this->newsletter_model->getmaillist();
    foreach()
    {
        $list = array('', '', '');
        $this->email->to($list);
    }
}

function getmaillist()
{

    $mail_list=array();
    $query=$this->db->get($this->_table);
    if($query->num_rows()>0)
    {
        foreach($query->result() as $row)
        {
            $mail_list[$row->user_id]['emailid']=$row->email_address;
        }
    }
    return $mail_list;
}
```

How can i get these email lists in foreach?   I don't know how to write in foreach

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand. You can add a comma separated list of people and email it to them.

```
$this->email->to('one@example.com, two@example.com, three@example.com');
```

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html

There is no need for a foreach loop.

```
$list = array('one@example.com', 'two@example.com', 'three@example.com');

$this->email->to($list);
```

EDIT:

Change your foreach statement to the following and see if that helps:

```
foreach($query->result() as $row)
{
    array_push($mail_list, $row->email_address);
}
```

Comment: i have to take the emailids from datadase..emailids are in $this->data['mail_list']

Comment: but i don't how to take it in foreach

Comment: emailids are in $this->data['mail_list']..then how can i?

Comment: If that list is an array then you can pass it into the `$this->email->to($this->newsletter_model->getmaillist());`

Comment: Severity: Warning

Message: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 753

Comment: @Ashitha what exactly returns $this->newsletter_model->getmaillist() ? Can you print_r it?

Comment: Array ( [2] => Array ( [emailid] => sdf@gmail.com ) [3] => Array ( [emailid] => test@gmail.com ) [4] => Array ( [emailid] => asd@gmail.com ) [5] => Array ( [emailid] => gallery2@gmail.com ) [6] => Array ( [emailid] => gallery1@gmail.com ) [7] => Array ( [emailid] => community1@gmail.com ) [8] => Array ( [emailid] => nathpraveens@gmail.com ) [9] => Array ( [emailid] => test@sd.com ) )

Comment: Well there's your problem. Each email is an array rather than just returning the string. You should probably work on that model.

Comment: Can you post the method for `getmaillist();` in the question section so I can see how you've written that code?

Comment: Updated my response. I'm basically updating the array with just the email address rather than creating a complex set of nested arrays.